# Database of signals for 1-d CNN Implementation in MATLAB

Tags: database, matlab, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm implementing CNN for signal classification problem, for which I need to create the database of the signals which I'll be giving as input to the CNN.

To create the database there is a function called `imageDatastore` and some other database functions, which will create the database of images only. If signals which are stored in .mat (*an array of size nx1*) format and are given to this function, it will create the database, but will give problem at the time of *trainNetwork*, error as unable to read the file.

This is the code I'm using to create the database, but its not working while training the network.

```
dbs = imageDatastore(fullfile(rootFolder, categories),'IncludeSubfolders', true, 'FileExtensions',{'.mat'}, 'LabelSource', 'foldernames');
```

What changes should I make in the existing functions so as to get the database of signals?

Answer (score 0):

Use datastore instead:

```
ims = datastore(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','nnet','nndemos', ...
    'nndatasets','A'),...
    'IncludeSubfolders',true,'Type', 'tabulartext');
```

For labels, pick it up through `imagedatastore`.